# Book on sufficient conditions for central limit theorem?

Tags: reference-request, central-limit-theorem

A few years ago, I took an advanced statics course where the Professor explained the the independent and identically distributed conditions are not necessairy for the Central limit theorem to hold. He mentioned that there was a book that had many results of sufficient conditions on the rvs (not independence and identically distributed), yet had Central Limit theorem like results. Any idea which book he might be refering to?